# Структура формата BMP

Tags: bmp, формат

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться со структурой файлов формата bmp.

Например не понимаю, как работает палитра при глубине цвета <= 8.

Так же есть монохромный формат, в котором используется только 2 цвета черный и белый, где 1 байт определяет цвет 8 пикселей (1 - белый, 0 - черный). А есть ли еще форматы? И как они все устроены?

Я правильно понимаю что bmp файлы с глубиной цвета от 1 до 8 устроены по одному принципу (с использованием палитры), от 16 до 32 по другому принципу. А вот монохромный это просто частный случай bmp файла с глубиной цвета 1. Придуманный для упрощения. Следовательно если я захочу я могу создать bmp файл с глубиной цвета = 1 с использованием палитры, а не где 1 байт это 8 пикселей? И все будет правильно работать?

Буду благодарен если кто нибудь, по полочкам разложит все форматы и их структуру или поделиться ссылкой на сайт, статью, видео или на что нибудь еще, где я смогу найти овтеты на свои вопросы.

Comment: Отличное описание различия пиксельных форматов bmp с примерами кода https://jenyay.net/Programming/Bmp

Comment: В однобитном bmp палитра есть, она не обязательно чёрно-белая

Comment: @MBo значит монохромный формат все же частный случай однобитного.